# When is countable direct-product of projective modules again projective ?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules, projective-modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. The Bass-Papp theorem states that any countable direct sum of injective $R$-modules is injective iff $R$ is Noetherian . Chase's theorem states that any direct product of projective $R$-modules is projective iff $R$ is Artinian . My question is : Is any  characterization for commutative rings (with unity) are known such that any countable direct-product of projective modules over the ring is again projective ?

Also asked on MSE : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2501945/when-is-countable-direct-product-of-projective-modules-again-projective

Comment: If $R$ is countable and $R^{\aleph_0}$ is projective, then $R$ is Artinian by Theorem 3.1 of http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1960-097-03/S0002-9947-1960-0120260-3/S0002-9947-1960-0120260-3.pdf. If $R^{\aleph_0}$ is free, then $R$ is a field by a theorem of Krull (I couldn't find a reference). If $R = \mathbb{Z}$ then $R^{\aleph_0}$ is not projective by Baer's theorem. Some sources claim that this also holds for any PID.

Comment: Have you looked into the book "Almost free modules" by Eklof and Mekler? I don't have my copy handy, but it seems to me there's probably some relevant information there, perhaps involving the notion of perfect rings.

Comment: @LucGuyot : I knew about Baer's result , I don't know whether it extends to any PID or not ... could you please present a proof of the theorem of Krull you mention that if $R^{\aleph_0}$ is free then $R$ is a field ?

Comment: @AndreasBlass : Ah no I haven't .. I will check it then as you say ..

Comment: @LucGuyot : A reference (no. 5) to this paper  https://cyber.sci-hub.cc/MTAuMTA4MC8wMDkyNzg3OTMwODgyNDc2Nw==/oneill1993.pdf  seems to deal with the question that when an infinite direct product of copies of $R$ is free , but I couldn't find this paper . If you have time , you may look for it and let me know if you find it.

Comment: @LucGuyot : Just a note that the theorem you state of Krull that $R^{\aleph_0}$ is free implies $R$ is a field, cannot be true because if $R$ is a local artinian ring then $R^{\aleph_0}$ is free over $R$

Comment: @users Indeed, the result of Krull I alluded to is incompletely stated (I found a quote in a book's exercise whose content is only partially available online). The things I know for sure are  written down in my answer below. The "Corollary" is my attempt to retrieve this result of Krull which, I guess, is more general than the corollary (maybe simply "$R$ is a domain" is sufficient). By the way, any update on "Almost free modules" by Eklof and Mekler? (I couldn't find anything useful in the too small online excerpts.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the assumption that a *countable direct product of modules over $R$* means a direct product of countably many modules over $R$, I answer OP's question when $R$ is **Noetherian**. In addition, I outline a remark for $R$ an arbitrary **countable** ring with identity.

> > **Claim 1.** Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. If $R$ is Noetherian then the following are equivalent:
>
> $(i)$ Every direct product of countably many projective modules over $R$ is projective.
>
> $(ii)$ $R$ is Artinian.
>
> > *Proof*. The implication $(ii) \Rightarrow (i)$ is given by Stephen Chase's Theorem [1, Theorems 3.3 and 3.4]. Assume that $(i)$ holds. Then $M  \Doteq R^{\aleph_0}$ is a projective module. If $R$ is moreover connected, then $M$ is free over $R$ by [2, Corollary 4.5]. $R$. By John O'Neill's result [3, Lemma 1.1], the ring $R$ is then Artinian. If $R$ is not connected, it is the direct product of finitely many non-trivial connected rings $R_i$. By hypothesis, the module $M_i \Doteq R_i^{\aleph_0}$ is projective over $R$, and hence over $R_i$, for every $i$. As $R$ is a product of finitely many Artinian rings, it is Artinian.

For an arbitrary countable ring, the following weaker result holds.

> > **Claim 2.** If $R$ is a countable ring with identity such that $R^{\aleph_0}$ is projective over $R$, then $R$ is left [perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_ring).
> >
> > *Proof.* Apply [1, Theorem 3.1] and Bass's characterization of left perfect rings.

Coming back to the commutative setting, we get

> > **Corollary.**
> >     Let $R$ be an integral domain. If $R$ is countable then the following are equivalent:
>
> $(i)$ Every direct product of countably many projective modules over $R$ is projective.
>
> $(ii)$ $R$ is a field.
>
> > *Proof.* Any element of a perfect commutative ring is either a unit or a zero divisor. The result is then a direct consequence of Claim 2.

---

[1] S. Chase, ["Direct product of modules"](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1960-097-03/S0002-9947-1960-0120260-3/S0002-9947-1960-0120260-3.pdf), 1960.
[2] H. Bass, ["Big projective modules are free"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.455.5945&rep=rep1&type=pdf), 1962.
[3] J. O'Neill, ["When a ring is an $F$-ring"](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0021869383710744/1-s2.0-S0021869383710744-main.pdf?_tid=2e77e806-c648-11e7-874f-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1510340078_14c303ff81fae85e7334cbe40c7f0106), 1993.

Comment: How do you apply Lemma 1.1 of J.O'Neil's paper ? How do you find a non-measurable cardinal $\alpha$ such that $R^\alpha$ is free or how do you find a cardinal number $\alpha \ge |R|$ such that $R^\alpha$ is free ? May be you should apply Corollary 3.2 ?

Comment: $\aleph_0$ is non-measurable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal).

Comment: Ah right I forgot ... measurable cardinals had to be uncountable ... thanks a lot for your contribution